# Shiny Server on NGINX with SSL

Tags: r, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, shiny-server

I have a Shiny Server, R 'shiny' package v7.0, NGINX and 3rd party SSL certificate set up on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit system. Everything worked fine when using http, but after I set up a SSL reverse proxy with NGINX - the server.R files stopped working - I don't see anything happening. I see only output from ui.R, no errors, but no results from server.R either. It looks like there's no communication between client a server. I tried IE8 and Google Chrome on Win 7, Google Chrome and Chromium on Ubuntu 12.04 notebook. Same issue. Interestingly though, that it **works fine** when using **iPad**.

Please help. Thanks

```
Shiny Server v0.3.6 (Node.js v0.10.21)

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.7.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-5  caTools_1.14  digest_0.6.3  httpuv_1.2.0  RJSONIO_1.0-3
[6] xtable_1.7-1
```

This is the log for Shiny-Server:

```
^[[32m[2013-11-12 03:53:43.571] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStopping listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
^[[32m[2013-11-12 03:53:43.572] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShutting down worker processes (with notification)
^[[32m[2013-11-12 03:53:44.393] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mShiny Server v0.3.6 (Node.js v0.10.21)
^[[32m[2013-11-12 03:53:44.395] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mUsing config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"
^[[32m[2013-11-12 03:53:44.435] [INFO] shiny-server - ^[[39mStarting listener on 0.0.0.0:3838
```

This is nginx.conf file (showing server section only):

```
server {

  listen 80;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {

  listen 443 default ssl;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

  server_name [domain name];
  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
    proxy_redirect http://localhost:3838/ $scheme://$host/;

  }

}
```

Comment: just for the record: are you using shiny pro or the open source version here?

Comment: That was open-source version. The pro one was not released at the time of the posting yet.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the root cause of the problem was not easy to understand as it worked fine on iPad
but not on other systems. So, after I found out that there was a new software version Shine Server 0.4.0.0 out there, I have made a move for an upgrade and also I have upgraded the 'shiny' package to shiny_0.8.0.99. After everything was done based on the instructions from this resource: http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/   -   the issue has gone. Thanks.